# Prevent image reload on filtering adapter data [Android]

Tags: java, android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

I am calling the filter data function from the fragment search view , it is working fine and the data are getting filtered but the images are getting reloaded.How can this be prevented

```
public menuadapter(ArrayList<GridItem> mGridDat, Context context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
    this.mGridData=new ArrayList<GridItem>();
    this.orignallist=new ArrayList<GridItem>();
    mGridData.addAll(mGridDat);
    orignallist.addAll(mGridDat);
    this.context = context;
    this.listener = listener;
    this.Session=new session(context);
}

public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Activity activity = (Activity)context;


    String capital=mGridData.get(position).getTitle().substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+mGridData.get(position).getTitle().substring(1).toLowerCase();
        holder.txtview.setText(capital);

        Picasso.with(context).load(mGridData.get(position).getImage()).fit().centerCrop().skipMemoryCache().into(holder.imageView);
    }
```

Filter Data function

```
    public void filterData(String query){
            query=query.toLowerCase();
            //Log.v("check1",String.valueOf(orignallist.size()));
            mGridData.clear();
            if(query.isEmpty()){
                mGridData.addAll(orignallist);
                // Log.v("check2",String.valueOf(orignallist.size()));
            }
        else {
            //Log.v("check0",String.valueOf(orignallist.size()));
            ArrayList<GridItem> newlist = new ArrayList<>();
            for(GridItem gd: orignallist) {

                if ((gd.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(query))  ) {
                    newlist.add(gd);
                }
            }

            if(newlist.size()> 0){

                mGridData.addAll(newlist);
            }

        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Why are you doing `skipMemoryCache()` then?

Comment: Because it showed previous image even if it was changed

Comment: You need to be using cache and cancel your images loading properly then:    public void cleanup() {
        Picasso.with(image.getContext())
            .cancelRequest(image);
        image.setImageDrawable(null);
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    Picasso.with(context).load(mGridData.get(position).getImage()).fit().centerCrop().networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).into(holder.imageView);
```

You need to use below property and **not** `skipMemoryCache()`

> OFFLINE
>
> public static final NetworkPolicy OFFLINE
>
> Forces the request through the disk cache only, skipping network.

https://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/NetworkPolicy.html

Answer (score 1):

To avoid reloding of images, solutions I think of are

1. one is to remove the images which are not matching the query and keeping others. Something like -

   ```
   if(!(gd.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(query)))
   {
   // get it from holder.getAdapterPosition();
       contentsArrayList.remove(position);     
       notifyItemRemoved(position);
   }

   // out of for loop
   notifyItemRangeChanged(firstRemovedPostion,contentsArrayList.size());
   ```
2. You can hide the element which is not matching the query and then show if it's matching another

`itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);`